# Detect all UIWebViews load finish : Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, webviewdidfinishload

As mentioned in the title, I'm looking out for the way to detect all of the UIWebViews has finished load that are loading HTML string simultaneously.

I have one custom view in which there are 5 web views (1 for question and 4 for options). Each of them loading html string as :

```
[queWV loadHTMLString:queHtml baseURL:nil];
[opt1WV loadHTMLString:opt1Html baseURL:nil];
[opt2WV loadHTMLString:opt2Html baseURL:nil];
[opt3WV loadHTMLString:opt3Html baseURL:nil];
[opt4WV loadHTMLString:opt4Html baseURL:nil];
```

I've tried checking this with webViewDidFinishLoad

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
     if(webView == opt4WV)
     {
         //All web views has finished loading
     }    
}
```

But practically, its incorrect as the webViewDidFinishLoad method is getting called for random web views, depending on contents to load.

Is there any way to detect load finish for all the web views ?

Thanks !

Comment: you can use some boolean variables to detect each webview finish loading.

Comment: yea, I think there we can maintain counter or an array, but sometimes there might be 3 or 6 webviews, dpending on number of options. Is there any other robust way to achieve it ?

Comment: can you get the exact figure about how many webviews loading at a time ?

Comment: as of now, NO. Will check it.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe I'm oversimplifying or not seeing something, but did you try to use webViewDidFinishLoad in a combination with the counter? So if you have 5 web views, implement a counter from 1 to 5 and count how many times does webViewDidFinishLoad get's called. When you get to 5 all views are loaded.

Comment: yes, for that i will require to keep track of number of webviews loading.

Answer (score 3):

yes, use a counter to keep track and make sure all web views delegate are set to the same controller

Answer (score 2):

in .h file create one counter like this

```
int webViewLoadCount = 0;
```

then  trke this counter like this way

in .m file UIWebview delegate method

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
NSString *string = webView.request.URL.absoluteString;

    if ([string rangeOfString:queHtml]) {
        NSLog(@"queWV webview loaded with this  %@ ",queHtml);
        webViewLoadCount = webViewLoadCount + 1;
    } else if ([string rangeOfString:opt1Html]) {
        NSLog(@"opt1WV webview loaded with this  %@ ",opt1Html);
        webViewLoadCount = webViewLoadCount + 1;
    } else if ([string rangeOfString:opt2Html]) {
        NSLog(@"opt2WV webview loaded with this  %@ ",opt2Html);
        webViewLoadCount = webViewLoadCount + 1;
    }else if ([string rangeOfString:opt3Html]) {
        NSLog(@"opt3WV webview loaded with this  %@ ",opt3Html);
        webViewLoadCount = webViewLoadCount + 1;
    }else if ([string rangeOfString:opt4Html]) {
        NSLog(@"opt4WV webview loaded with this  %@ ",opt4Html);
        webViewLoadCount = webViewLoadCount + 1;
    }
}
```

i hope this will help you

Answer (score 2):

May be helpful

take a `NSInteger counter;` globally

in `viewDidLoad` initialise `counter = 0;`

then

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
 counter++;

 if(counter == 5)
 {
     //All web views has finished loading
     counter = 0; //again reset to 0
 }    
}
```

Happy coding...

Answer (score 1):

declare the variable, "loaded" out of this function

```html
int loaded = 0

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
     if(webView == queWV || webView == opt1WV || webView == opt2WV || webView == opt3WV || webView == opt4WV )
     {
         loaded += 1;
     }    
    
      if (loaded ==5) {
        // process
      }
}
```